# ConnectionString For Getting An Excel File Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, connection-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ConnectionString For Getting An Excel  File Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971723/connectionstring-for-getting-an-excel-file-problem)

hi my Dear Friends :

in have an Excel File Named (a.xlsx) in A Folder Named (ExcelFiles).

ExcelFiles Foldre Is in the root Of project.

so my connctionstring for getting excel file data is like this :

```
<add name="xlsx" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=aaa\ExcelFiles\a.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"/>
```

aaa = My Project Name

with this connection string every thing is ok in local , but after upload web site i have an error.

where is the problem??

is this path true -> ~/ExcelFiles/a.xlsx or not

can u fix this path 4 me....

thanks in future advance

best regards

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971723/connectionstring-for-getting-an-excel-file-problem

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you told us the error message you are getting on the server.

But since this only occurs on the server, first verify that the provider beiing used is installed on the server: `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`. [It is in the Office 2007 Data Access Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891&displaylang=en).

Comment: SO SORRY / THAT WAS MY MISTAKE / THANKS 4 CLEAN IT UP